# Not able to append options to select

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am not sure why this works but not when I pass in numbers

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div id="facebookPhotos-iFrameContent">
        <div>
            <p>Log in</p>
            <p id="LoginButtonContainer"><input type="image" id="btnLogin" src="images/loginBtn.jpg" /></p>
            <p><select id="facebookAlbumDropdown" /></p>
            <div id="facebookPhotosContainer" />
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

```
AddDropdownItem("-Select something test-", "-1", "testDropdown");

function AddDropdownItem(sText, sValue, sDropdownID)
{
      $("#" + sDropdownID).append("<option value=" + sValue + ">" + sText + "</option>");
}
```

that works

but this does not:

```
var id = 104388426283811;
AddDropdownItem("-Select something test-", id.toString(), "testDropdown");
```

What happens is the default option shows up but then when it tries to add the second option it bombs out with no errors that I can see in the firebug console and then in the end the list goes blank (no options) when my code is done running.

Comment: I took your code and put it in a simple HTML file to test.  I didn't get any errors -- the options loaded fine.  I did this in IE8 and FF3.6.  Can you post more of your code?  I'm not sure what default option you're referring to (is it the first one added)?  Maybe that's causing the problem?

Comment: Ok, this code is working (without the toString which I had tried before) but doesn't like the last option I try to add.  Here's the incoming params to the add method: sText: "Profile Pictures"  sValue = 100001379631246 sDropdownID = "testDropdown"

Comment: and here's the first (well second ..after the default option) that seems to be fine and is added successfully:  sText = "Test Test2"  sValue = 104388426283811 sDropdownID = "testDropdown"

Comment: I don't see why it'd have a problem with the later option that it's adding which is option #3 for that Profile Pictures value

Comment: I'm trying it on my end and there is no error at all (Chrome, FF, IE).

Comment: Byron, how did you form your starting and ending select tag in your page, same way I did?

Comment: What other JavaScript do you have in your page?  It's looking like there's something else that's causing your problem.

Comment: possibly, but why wouldn't I be seeing any js errors in the console if there are other problems?  Do you mean logical problems or errors?

Comment: Perhaps logical problems.  You're saying you don't see any errors that you can see in firebug and everything in the select goes blank.  Maybe there's some additional script that's running that's clearing out the select.  Maybe something else in your `$(document).ready()`?  I'm guessing here but am just considering what else could be wrong since my sample and Byron's worked.

Comment: there's no other logic after that point...

Comment: Where is everything located?  Is AddDropDownItem, your jQuery script tag, etc., all contained in the iframe...or are you calling AddDropDownItem to/from your iframe?  It may have to do with the iframe and parent window and how they interact.

Comment: a couple of oddities are happening.  As each append runs, a) I see the dropdown get wider for the text but see no text.  b) After it adds another option, the previous option seems to be deleted because I can see the dropdown change size again to accommodate the next item's text value length.  In the end I see the dropdown accommodate the last option addition but then the entire dropdown completely collapses once my code is done leaving it with no values at all.

Comment: ok I'm seeing a postback at the end which doesn't make any sense...I'm not forcing any postback.  I am clicking a button so I guess then that's wiping away what was added to the select.  So this is supposed to be all async calls here.  Should I not be using a submit button so that it doesn't cause a postback?

Comment: Weird.  Any chance you could post the code you're working with (removing extraneous and proprietary stuff)?  Just feels like I'm guessing without seeing what you're seeing.  Also, how different is the logic that Byron posted to what you're doing?

Comment: That's probably it!  In your code to handle the button click, is that also in jQuery?  Do something like `$("#btnClick").click(function(e) { e.preventDefault(); //rest of logic });` and see if that works.  A submit button's default behavior is to post back.  You could also change it to `<button id='xxx'>Click Me</button>` or an `<input type='button' id='xxx' .../>` and it should work.

Comment: I posted my code as an answer below.  You can see how I wired up the preventDefault call.  Hopefully that helps.

Comment: I added e.preventDefault(); but it doesn't recognize preventDefault();

Comment: I'm not really using a submit button but rather an input (image)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the comment thread in the original question, here's my sample page that incorporates your logic (along with wiring up a button to add options to the select):

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>jQuery Test</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript"> 
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#btnClick").click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var id = 104388426283811;
            AddDropdownItem("-Select something test-", id.toString(), "testDropdown");
            //AddDropdownItem("-Select something test-", "-1", "testDropdown");
        });
    });

    function AddDropdownItem(sText, sValue, sDropdownID)
    {
          $("#" + sDropdownID).append("<option value='" + sValue + "'>" + sText + "</option>");
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>

 <input id='btnClick' type='submit' value='click'></input>
<p><select name="MyTestDropdown" id="testDropdown"></select></p>


</body>
</html>
```

I don't have the iframes that you mentioned, but I'm using an `input submit` element to add items in.  I'm preventing the default behavior of a submit button by calling `e.preventDefault();`, which then prevents the post back.  I'm then able to add items to the `select` element.

I hope this helps.

Comment: so after the DOM loads it's sending what as e back to you?  the DOM as an object?

Comment: I see you're also using a submit, mine's an image

Comment: It's the element (event object) that's handling the event.  In this case, the submit button.  Here's the jQuery API entry for this object and the functions/props associated to it.  http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/

Comment: `<input type='image' ...>` is a submit button with an image.  Same thing -- it should try to submit the form when you click it.  Use `preventDefault` to prevent it from doing that and you should be good.

Comment: Awesome!  Glad you got it working.  That was a lot of comments.  :)  Later.

Answer (score 2):

JavaScript will interpret integers as strings where needed, there is no need to use `toString()`.

Comment: id is a primitive type?  it's set to an integer

Comment: This makes no difference since id is an int. toString() or no, it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Try putting the value in single quotes, like this:

```
function AddDropdownItem(sText, sValue, sDropdownID)
{
      $("#" + sDropdownID).append("<option value='" + sValue + "'>" + sText + "</option>");
}
```

You asked, "Why would that matter." The answer. It is a good practice and it prevents problems when your values start having spaces in them. I ALWAYS put attribute values in quotes.

Now, for your problem... I just tried it with the following code and it works like a charm!

```
<p><select name="MyTestDropdown" id="testDropdown"></select></p>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

        AddDropdownItem("-Select something test-", "-1", "testDropdown");
        AddDropdownItem("something else", "1", "testDropdown");
        AddDropdownItem("another thing", 2, "testDropdown");

        var id = 104388426283811;
        AddDropdownItem("test big value", id.toString(), "testDropdown");

        AddDropdownItem("Profile Pictures", 100001379631246, "testDropdown");

        AddDropdownItem("Test Test2", 104388426283811, "testDropdown");

    });
    function AddDropdownItem(sText, sValue, sDropdownID)
    {
        $("#" + sDropdownID).append("<option value='" + sValue + "'>" + sText + "</option>");
    }
</script>
```

Your original code actually works, too. I don't think there was a problem with it. :) Maybe you have a problem elsewhere in your code?

Comment: so that would get rid of or tolerate any spaces?  putting in the single quotes?

Comment: It would tolerate spaces. Not a big deal for numbers or when you always have one word, but if you get in the habit of always using quotes (single or double), you free yourself from SO many problems in the future.